# SSRS reporting | Multiple worksheets using different datasets

Tags: reporting-services, worksheet-function

I am using SSRS to imbed some of my reports. I can see that we can have single Dataset associated with one report and we can only have one worksheet.

I have 2 datasets which i want to imbed in single sheet but in different worksheets.

Lets say, i have DS1 which i would like to imbed in Sheet1
and DS2, would be in Sheet2, but in same excel.

Please suggest if this is something possible? Just to inform you that i have different columns in both DS1 and DS2

Comment: You can have multiple datasets and multiple tables that use the different datasets. Tables can use any dataset that you add. You just can't (easily) use the data from two dataset in a single table.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to output two tables onto two different worksheets in the same workbook. @kawade you can do this. Look at the PageName property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/pagination-in-reporting-services-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15